# Displaying remote images in a firefox add-on panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to display remote images in a FireFox add-on panel, but the `src` attributes are being converted from something like this:

`http://example.com/image.jpg`

to something like this:

`resource://addon_name/data/%22http://example.com/image.jpg%22`

I can't figure out if I'm breaking a security policy or not.

In my add-on script (index.js) I'm retrieving image URLs using the sdk/request API and passing them to my content script (data/my-panel.js). My data/my-panel.js file is creating DOM elements in my panel file (data/popup.html) – including images – using the URLs passed from index.js. Here are the relevant bits of code:

`index.js`

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  contentURL: "./popup.html",
  contentScriptFile: "./my-panel.js"
});
  Request({
      url: url,
      onComplete: function(response) {
           // Get the JSON data.
          json = response.json;
          // Launch the popup/panel.
          panel.show();
          panel.port.emit("sendJSON", json);
      }
  }).get();
```

`data/my-panel.js`

```
var title;
var desc;
var list;
var titleTextNode;   
var descTextNode; 

self.port.on("sendJSON", function(json) {

    json.docs.forEach(function(items) {
        title = JSON.stringify(items.sourceResource.title);
        desc = JSON.stringify(items.sourceResource.description);
        img = JSON.stringify(items.object);       
        console.log(img);
        var node = document.createElement("li");                 // Create a <li> node
        var imgTag = document.createElement("img");                 // Create a <img> node
        imgTag.setAttribute('src', img);
        imgTag.setAttribute('alt', desc);
        imgTag.style.width= '25px';
        titleTextNode = document.createTextNode(title);
        descTextNode = document.createTextNode(desc);
        node.appendChild(titleTextNode);                         // Append the text to <li>
        node.appendChild(descTextNode);                          // Append the text to <li>
        document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);     // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
        document.getElementById("myImgs").appendChild(imgTag);
    });
});
```

The `console.log(img)` line is displaying the URLs correctly, but not in popup.html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <ul id="myList"></ul>
    <p id="myImgs"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the images' `src` attributes point directly to the remote URLs?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Using JSON.stringify() on the img URL was adding double quotes around it. Removing it fixed the images:

`img = items.object;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about SDK permissions, but as a last resort you can turn the remote url into a resource URI like this -

```
var res = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandler);
res.setSubstitution("rawr", Services.io.newURI('http://www.bing.com/',null,null));

// now try navigating to resource://rawr it will load bing
```

Then you can load `resource://rawr` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart. I'll see if I can get that working tomorrow.